# Print (display) reference category in R's lm summary?

Tags: r, printing, display, lm, summary

How can you print the reference category used when a categorical/nominal variable is entered into a linear model. Here's an example:

`summary(lm(data = iris, Sepal.Length ~ Species))`

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         5.0060     0.0728   68.76  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor   0.9300     0.1030    9.03  8.8e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica    1.5820     0.1030   15.37  < 2e-16 ***
```

Here's what I'd like:

```
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         5.0060     0.0728   68.76  < 2e-16 ***
**Reference: Speciessetosa**
Speciesversicolor   0.9300     0.1030    9.03  8.8e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica    1.5820     0.1030   15.37  < 2e-16 ***
```

If there is a way to make this work generally (when there are multiple categorical predictors, then each reference group is easily identifiable), that would be most excellent. And if there is a way to make the formatting particularly clear, that would be doubly excellent (I'm not beholden to the example formatting above).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that your intercept is zero.

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species + 0, data = iris))
#Coefficients:
#                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#Speciessetosa       5.0060     0.0728   68.76   <2e-16 ***
#Speciesversicolor   5.9360     0.0728   81.54   <2e-16 ***
#Speciesvirginica    6.5880     0.0728   90.49   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the results. I'm looking to display the reference group NAME, not the results without an intercept.